# Powershell access property stored in JSON object

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-4.0

```
$primaryEndpoints = az storage account show --resource-group rg --name sto --query 'primaryEndpoints'
```

The above command returns

```
{
  "blob": "https://sto.blob.core.windows.net/",
  "dfs": null,
  "file": "https://sto.file.core.windows.net/",
  "internetEndpoints": null,
  "microsoftEndpoints": null,
  "queue": "https://sto.queue.core.windows.net/",
  "table": "https://sto.table.core.windows.net/",
  "web": null
}
```

But his command below returns nothing :

```
echo $primaryEndpoints["blob"]
```

I've also tried

```
echo $primaryEndpoints.blob
```

How do I access the json property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are getting a JSON string as a return value. To access the properties by name, you need to first convert the JSON string to a PSObject.

```bsh
$primaryEndpoints = az storage account show --resource-group rg --name sto --query 'primaryEndpoints'

$primaryEndpointObjects = $primaryEndpoints | ConvertFrom-Json

$primaryEndpointObjects.blob
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.